Check progress when running ansible-pull with cloud-init
I am provisioning an Ubuntu VM in Kubernetes. To set it up I am using ansible.
How can I see the logs of ansible-pull executed in cloud-init?
I would like to monitor the process and check when it's done.
This is a sample of what I am using:
        - cloudInitNoCloud:
            userData: |-
              #cloud-config
              packages:
                - ansible
              runcmd:
                - ansible-pull -U https://...

I tried looking for logs in /var/log, but found nothing relevant.

I found a workaround: using tee to pipe the logging into a file:
ansible-pull -U https://... | tee -a /var/log/ansible-pull.log

